# is it possible to do inline function in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

the question is in the title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inlining is the responsibility of the CLR (JIT) and there are some conditions as to when a function is inlined:

1. The code size is smaller than 32 bytes of IL.
2. The function does not contain "complex" constructs, e.g. loops, switch etc.
3. The function does not contain try/catch/finally.
4. The function is not declared as virtual.

As you will probably find out, 32 bytes is **not very much** in terms of code, it is suitable for quick and small if-else condition testing, property getters/setters. I don't think you can gain any speed from inlining a bigger amount of code.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation about the conditions for inlining?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/01/14/58703.aspx

Comment: thanks, sadly I will have to keep my long function and the ugly part is, the code inside that function is copy/pasted in many other function

Comment: Another good overview at http://blogs.msdn.com/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx

Comment: If you have 36 byes of IL, and the function is being called from a tight loop.  Why put it in a separate function then?  Code-reuse and documentation.  The JIT should be more flexible, like it is in Java.

Comment: So if I have one line of code in a method just for clarification purposes of what that line of code is doing then the compiler will automatically inline it?

Answer (score 16):

The answers I've seen assume you're talking about compile or JIT-time inlining - and they're entirely correct. However, the other use of the word "inline" that I've heard is for things like lambda expressions - in C#, things like:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 5, 2, 5, 6 };

    return numbers.Select(x => x+10);
}
```

The `x => x+10` (a lambda expression) can be regarded as an "inline function" in source code terms, in that it's an extra function declared "inline" in another method.

And yes, VB9 has this:

```
Dim len As Func(Of String, Integer) = Function(x) x.Length       
Console.WriteLine(len("foo"))
```

I believe there are more restrictions in VB9 compared with C# though - for instance, I don't *think* you can create an `Action<T>` (or any other delegate type with a void return type) using a lambda expression in VB9, whereas it's easy in C#. Likewise I believe the lambda has to be just a single expression in VB9, whereas in C# it can be a whole block in braces.

As of VB10, you can create multi-line lambda expressions in VB too.

Of course, if the question was really referring to the execution rather than the source code, all of this is irrelevant :)

Comment: Okay, so now it's obvious that this answer is irrelevant to the actual question. However, it *may* be relevant if someone hits this page when trying to find the answer to a different question. Should I delete it or not? Thoughts?

Comment: You should not delete it! It just helped me.

Comment: While at the time that you wrote this the VB limitations that you mentioned were correct, These limitations no longer exist.  I just wanted to point that out for anyone else who is looking for this answer now.

Comment: @Jesse: Will clarify.

Answer (score 7):

this question still have some activities 5 years later (already???)

[with .net 4.5 it is now possible to specify inline method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

simply use this attribut

```
<MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)>
```

Answer (score 2):

The .NET team has wisely decided that such features have no place in the programming language itself since the compiler is better in deciding what to inline anyway. That's putting it rather aggressively but the fact is that modern C++ actually often disregard the `inline` instruction for their decision-making process about which functions to inline.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one scenario when it would be a nice facility:

We have a standard logging function to which it is often useful to pass the caller's name.  However, if logging is set to a low verbosity, the logging function simply returns to aid performance.  To avoid the caller making CPU-expensive calls to System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, only for the logging function to not use them, it would be nice if we could create an inline function which decided in advance whether to bother finding out the method's name:

```
Public Inline Function GetMyname(iLogLevel) as string
  if iLogLevel < 3 then return ""
  return System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name()
End Function
```

Then in the caller, we could have put a neat line like:

Log(2,GetMyname(2) & ": Something happened")

But if the compiler decides not to inline GetMyname() (as it surely would) then the methodname that would appear in the log would always be "GetMyName" - no use at all.

Call me old fashioned, but if we start leaving all decisions to the compiler (or the CLR!) then we may as well look for a new career and leave it to "the .Net team".  Sometimes, software designers DO actually know best?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a function as inline explicitly, but the JIT optimizer is free to inline functions if it sees the benefit.

Comment: @Fredou: the question is: why would you want to?

Comment: @Konrad I got some big function and I want to split it, when I do it I lose execution speed

Comment: @Fredou: I would doubt such a benchmark in principle. It seems unlikely that you can draw any significant performance gain by tricking the JITter on such a low level. If the function is big, function call overhead should be insignificant, and I even doubt that it could be reliably measured at all.

Comment: @Fredou: (cont') … however, it's true that there may be edge cases. For example, I've found that an own implementation of the List<> class will *never* equal the native implementation performance-wise. Clearly, there's some magic involved that makes the JITter aware of specific code.

Comment: @ Konrad, when I split the function, I lose about 18% execution speed

Comment: You are programming in a managed language. Ideally you shouldn't assume anything about the platform you want to run your code on (how do you think it's not an ARM machine?!). You *shouldn't* be the one who optimizes code at this level. If it's really important, you should've been using C/C++ :)

Answer (score 0):

Noting Tom's issue of May `11, I'd have to say that if you have an application that is *truly* performance critical, then using a language that depends on the CLR is probably not your best option.

In fact, an object-oriented design probably isn't your best choice either.  You might want to seriously look at C as an alternative.

Comment: Are there really only two scenarios: one in which the entire application is absolutely performance critical, and design should be abandoned in favor of efficiency, and the other in which design trumps all, there is no need to optimize as long as you can throw more hardware at it?

Is there no condition in which an application should both run on the CLR *and* attempt to be efficient in places? Should large applications simply be rewritten in C whenever performance concerns arise?